# How do I configure a flow to send to multiple PODs in K8S?

Tags: asynchronous, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have single camunda job that is configured as a multi-instance call to another process.  At present, multi instance asynchronous before, multi instance asynchronous after, and multi instance exclusive are all checked.  We have multiple PODs deployed to handle the calls(1k at a time) and right now when I try to run this, it seems like no matter what I am doing, it is running them serially, or close to it.  What is needed to actually send all 1000 elements to multiple instances of the child process?

Tried configuring the multi instance asynch settings

Multi Instance
Loop Cardinality-blank
Collection-builtJobList
Element Variable-builtRequestObject

I then have all three multi instance values checked.  The Asynch Continuations are not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Camunda BPM will only run a single thread (execution) within a given process instance at a time by default. You can change that behavior for a given task/activity by checking the "Asynchronous Before" and/or "Asynchronous After" checkboxes - thus electing to use the Job Executor - **and** deselecting the "Exclusive" checkbox. (This also applies to the similar checkboxes for multi-instance activities.) If you do that, beware that the behavior may not be what you want; specifically:

- You will likely receive OptimisticLockingExceptions if you have a decent number of threads running simultaneously on a single instance. These are thrown when the individual threads attempt to update the information in the relational database for the process instance and discover that the data has been modified while they were performing their processing.
- If those OptimisticLockingExceptions occur, the Job Executor will automatically retry the Job *without decrementing the available retries*. This will re-execute the Job, re-executing any included integration logic as well. This may not be desirable.

Although Camunda BPM has been proven to be fantastic at executing large numbers of process instances in parallel, it isn't designed to execute multiple threads simultaneously within an individual process instance. If you want that behavior within a given process instance, I would suggest that you handle the threading yourself within an individual Service Task, fire-and-forget launching the threads you need and letting the Service Task complete within Camunda immediately after launching them... of course if that's feasible given your application's desired behavior.